# How to descrease SQL queries count generated by model method in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have model method that calculates object status using some data that is not "ForeignKey"

```
class Product(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def status(self):
        sales_data = Sale.objects \
                         .filter(
                         some_string_parameter='goods',
                         entity_ref=self.id
                         ) \
                     .aggregate(Max('discount')).get('discount')

        if not sales_data:
            return "No Sale"
        elif sales_data >= 50:
            return "Sale over 50%"
        elif sales_data < 50:
            return "Sale less than 50"

class Sale(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    some_string_parameter = models.CharField(max_length=100) # define reffering entity type
    entity_ref = models.BigAutoField() # refer to various entities types
    discount = models.IntegerField() # amount of discount
```

I have a page with the product list (all products in the database) where I need to show its status.

```
{% for product in products %}

    {{ product.name }} - {{ product.status }}

{% endfor %}
```

Each `product.status` generates extra SQL request. Is there any way to "prefetch" model method result for all objects in queryset?

Comment: Please share your `Sale` model.

Comment: `entity_ref = models.BigAutoField()` why do this? Use a `ForeignKey` instead (even the content types framework would have been better if it refers to multiple models, still I would prefer generalization/specialization (in the context of database normalization) instead of content types framework though)...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem done. There is no way to directly relate Sale to Product using ForeignKey because Sale contains data for various other entity types using modifier.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat There is no way to use foreignKey because Sale model contains data for various entities, not only for Product, but for Estate, Service models and etc.
To define entity type used 'some_string_parameter' in the Sale model.
Database structure was built not using Django, so it is as-is.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat hm, looks like I need to use a content types framework to establish foreignKey between these models?

Comment: @rez0n have a look at the [contenttypes framework (django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) it does things similar to what you do, but the major benefit is it is _supported_ by the ORM (still I don't prefer using this).

Comment: @rez0n: even with these modifiers, it still makes sense to add a relation, perhaps a relation to the `Modifier`, that then relates to the product.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem btw foreignKey does not resolve the extra query to the database when `product.status` is called.

Comment: @rez0n: it can: if you query forward with a `ForeignKey`, you can use [**`select_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and this will thus "piggyback" on the query, you can also work with a `ForeignKey` in *reverse*, and use [**`prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which will result in *one* additional query, but not one *per* product, just *two* queries to load the sales and the `Product`s. Furthermore we can make use of `.annotate(..)` to effectively perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm tried to establish relation but looks like there is no way (at least documented), probably you have an idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625721/how-to-estabilish-contenttype-relation-in-django-for-laravel-polymorphic-related